# How to exit a batch program upon error?

Tags: dos, stderr

I've got a batch file that does several things. If one of them fails, I want to exit the whole program. For example:

```
@echo off
type foo.txt 2>> error.txt >> success.txt
mkdir bob
```

If the file foo.txt isn't found then I want the stderr message appended to the error.txt file, else the contents of foo.txt is appended to success.txt. Basically, if the type command returns a stderr then I want the batch file to exit and not create a new directory. How can you tell if an error occurred and decide if you need to continue to the next command or not?

Comment: I added the code

IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 EXIT /B
echo %errorlevel%

before the mkdir bob command, but regardless of the value of ERRORLEVEL (i.e. 0 or 1) the directory is still created. So basically, ERRORLEVEL is being set with a different value whether the type command finds the file or not, but the program is not exiting. Thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

use `ERRORLEVEL` to check the exit code of the previous command:

```
 if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit /b
```

**EDIT**: documentation says "condition is true if the exit code of the last command is EQUAL or GREATER than X" (you can check this with `if /?`). aside from this, you could also check if the file exists with

```
 if exist foo.txt echo yada yada
```

to execute multple commands if the condition is true:

```
 if ERRORLEVEL 1 ( echo error in previous command & exit /b )
```

or

```
 if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo error in previous command
    exit /b
 )
```